# Check if tree is a heap

Tags: .net, functional-programming, f#

I'm trying to create a function **chkHeapProperty** that will check if a given heap is fulfilling the heap requirement: *"The value stored in a node must be less than or equal than it's children nodes"*
Example of a heap:

```
  1
 / \
2   3
```

```
let rec chkHeapProperty heap =
    match heap with
    | EmptyHP -> true
    | HP(root, leftHeap, rightHeap) when root < leftHeap && root < rightHeap -> true
```

This is how I've gotten. My first idea was to traverse all the nodes and put them into a list and then iterate through that list but I feel like there must be a more efficient way and more functional. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the root of this tree is smaller than the roots of both its subtrees, *and* the subtrees are also heaps, this root must also be smaller than all the elements of the subtrees.
(Take a few moments to convince yourself that this is true.)

Thus, you don't need to traverse all the children and grandchildren (et cetera), you only need to check the root of each subtree and then check the "heapness" of the subtrees recursively.

This is easier if you define a helper function first,

```
let lesser x heap = match heap with
    | EmptyHP -> true
    | HP(root, _, _) -> x <= root
```

and then,

```
let rec isHeap heap = 
    match heap with
    | EmptyHP -> true
    | HP(r, h1, h2) -> lesser r h1 && lesser r h2 && isHeap h1 && isHeap h2
```